# Jasper não abre fora da IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport, jasper-reports, relatório

Dentro da IDE NetBeans o código funciona e o relatório é apresentado.
Mas ao gerar o executável, não é possivel abrir o relatório, recebendo a mensagem de nulo.
É como se ele não conseguisse localizar o relatório.

```
public ClienteREL() {
    this.path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
    this.pathToReportPackage = this.path + "br/com/prologica/report/";


            System.out.println(this.pathToReportPackage);

}


//Imprime/gera uma lista de Clientes
public void imprimir(List<Cliente> clientes) throws Exception   
{
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.getPathToReportPackage() + "imprimir.jrxml");

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(clientes));

            JasperPrintManager jasperPrintManager = null;
            jasperPrintManager.printReport(print, false);

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você está gerando um jar? Se sim, tente executa-lo direto do prompt e veja se estoura algum erro.

Comment: pois amigo, ao executar no console é como se ele não conseguisse encontrar o relatório.

Comment: Executar o jar no console não exibe nada também?

Comment: nada... mas dentro da ide roda direitinho

Answer (score 1):

Isso claramente é algum problema de Classpath. O NetBeans por debaixo dos panos executa o JAR também por linha de comando. Então teria que ver como ele faz.

Recomendo você começar tentando rodar manualmente o JAR gerado pelo NetBeans dentro da pasta "`dist`" do seu projeto. Se isso der certo, copie a pasta "`dist`" com tudo o que há lá dentro (inclusive a pasta "`dist/libs`") para um outro lugar e tente executá-lo.

Se isto der errado, por favor, tente criar um exemplo [mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do seu problema.